# PL/SQL : how to display / export hierarchical tree with lines from table

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

I would like to know how can I display (`dbms_output` or `select`) or even better how to export hierarchical tree data (using `|  ____`  to show structure of tree).

Any ideas?

Let's say table is `employee` table (from practice) where you have `manager_id` and `department_id` connected

Comment: You want it to draw the structure of the tree?  This is not the type of task SQL is good at -- far better to have an ordered output with a "depth" column and then have a front end language / system draw your tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SQL> select substr(lpad(lpad('|-', level * 2, '| ') || ename,
  2                length(ename) + (level * 2 ),
  3                ' '
  4              ), 3) result
  5  from emp
  6  start with mgr is null
  7  connect by prior empno = mgr;

RESULT
-----------------------------------------------------------------
KING
|-JONES
| |-SCOTT
| | |-ADAMS
| |-FORD
| | |-SMITH
|-BLAKE
| |-ALLEN
| |-WARD
| |-MARTIN
| |-TURNER
| |-JAMES
|-CLARK
| |-MILLER

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Possible, but - ugly (in my opinion). Use some other tool (like Oracle Apex tree).